# css overflow-y on a load html page

Tags: html, css

I'm inserting a jsp page on an existing jsp page (left menu) to simplify my deployment and mutualize my menu in any page of my site.
Here is the insertion I'm performing:

```
<body>
....
<div style="overflow-y:scroll;" id="leftMenu"></div>
....
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#leftMenu").load("leftMenu.jsp");
        .....
    </script>
```

insertion is working well but I would need to get the y scroll available systematically but it is not working properly (on Chrome and Firefox and IE). Sometimes when I refresh the page I can see the vertical scrolling but this is not systematic.
I also tried to insert as well tag

> height: 100%

but same result, how can I get the vertical scrolling on this jsp page I'm inserting ?

Comment: what do you mean by "is not systematic" ? can you try to use `height: auto` or `height:inherit;`

Comment: sometimes I can see the y scrolling sometimes not....

Comment: do you want to view it at all no matter if the content itself larger than the div or you only want to view it automatically if the content size is larger than the div?

Comment: I tried both auto and inherit but it changes the position of the left menu, my main div is overlapping the left menu

Comment: I would need the left menu remaining static on x and would need to view it automatically if the content size is larger than the div

Comment: Do you somewere have `overflow-x: hidden;`? Cause it can conflict in some causes. Also make sure you don't have a `overflow` or `overflow-y` porperty overriding your `overflow-y: scroll` property.

Comment: yes my body is getting overflow-x: hidden; it can cause some conflicts ?

Comment: I removed overflow-x: hidden; but same result

Answer (score 0):

If I am right then:

If you always want a scrollbar whether it’s needed or not, 
use overflow:scroll.

Comment: even if I'm using oveflow:scroll I have the same result, the scrolling is not visible, I need to change the screen size of the browser to view the y scrolling bar visibile.

Answer (score 0):

Change the styles overflow style when you loading new JSP page

Keep the style  "overflow: hidden". If you don't want to scrollbar initially

eg.  when loading the new jsp

> $(document).ready(function() {
>           $("#leftMenu").load("leftMenu.jsp");
>           $("#leftMenu").css("overflow-y", "scroll");

Comment: same thing, the scrollbar is not displayed and I cannot scroll on the bottom part of my left menu, but if I'm opening the chrome debug tool (inspect) the scollbar is appearing....

Comment: I've also seen that if I'm changing the screen size, the y scrollbar is also appearing, but I would like to be visible on load of the page

Comment: Did you try overriding the css styles